# How to disconnect old team provider in Eclipse if plug-in is not installed

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, mercurial

I recently switched to Eclipse Indigo (from Galileo) and I also switched from SVN with subclipse to Mercurial (with MercurialEclipse) for version control. On new projects or existing projects that weren't under SVN control I can right-click and use Team->Share to set things up. On existing projects in the workspace that were under SVN, the Team context menu has Apply Patch... as the only option. I can't seem to find a way to disconnect SVN as the team provider. I am hoping to avoid reinstalling subclipse into Indigo just to be able to disconnect from it.